# Retry after catch

Tags: java, fortify, retry-logic

Here's the logic I used:

```
int retries = config.get("retries");
Response resp = null
do {
    try {
        resp = operation.execute();
        retries = 0;
    } catch (Exception ex) { //Note. Please excuse this catch pattern. Its not a problem now.
        if isAParticularException(ex) { //call a method to check the wrapped exception and other details
            retries--;
            LOGGER.info("Integrity exception, can be retried");
            if (retries == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("Retry exhausted");
                throw ex;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Retrying operation, retry count " + ledgerRetry);
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
} while (retries > 0);
return resp;
```

Number of retries is considering original operation as well. But the **problem** is that

1. if I return from try block directly without assigning anything, then SCA (Fortify for me) reports that the variable retries is not read (in success flow), and
2. if I assign and do as above, then SCA shouts about the immediate
   reassignment of value to the retries variable without even reading
   it.

**Considerations:**

1. The first call should be independent of whatever value we read for
   'retries'
2. Duplicate code should be avoided, and avoiding recursion will be
   nice too.

May be a simple thing, but I am not catching it probably. Please suggest.

Comment: Rather than catching *every* `Exception` and then testing if it's a specific one, catch the specific one directly. `catch(SpecificException ex)`

Comment: It checks for a particular exception wrapped inside a generic exception. And since that is used by many other methods, its written in a method. Thats not the main concern for Foritfy issue resolution by the way now.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use break instead of set retries to 0? I guess you sets retries after operation execute, because you want to break executing loop:

```
int retries = config.get("retries");
Response resp = null

do {
    try {
        resp = operation.execute();
        break;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if isAParticularException(ex) { //call a method to check the wrapped exception and other details
            retries--;
            LOGGER.info("Integrity exception, can be retried");
            if (retries == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("Retry exhausted");
                throw ex;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Retrying operation, retry count " + ledgerRetry);
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
} while (retries > 0);
return resp;
```

Or if you want you can return resp in try catch, and return null if did not execute anything:

```
int retries = config.get("retries");
Response resp = null

do {
    try {
        resp = operation.execute();
        return resp;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if isAParticularException(ex) { //call a method to check the wrapped exception and other details
            retries--;
            LOGGER.info("Integrity exception, can be retried");
            if (retries == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("Retry exhausted");
                throw ex;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Retrying operation, retry count " + ledgerRetry);
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
} while (retries > 0);
return null;
```

If I were you, I would consider throw exception instead of returning null.

Comment: In both of the snippets, SCA will complain about the variable `retries` not being used.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good practice but you can set retries to 0 if it is less than 0 and use while loop instead of do while, and check if retries is >= 0

Comment: Not for sure :-) Its boggling me because the retry value is not hardcoded. I dont think its a good practice though. Because for wrong values, it will not run. THis means I have two checks for same thing.

Comment: What if someone set retries to Integer.MIN_VALUE? if you execute retries-- you will have Integer.MAX_VALUE, and  while (retries > 0) will be true